# Divisibility by $2$ and powers of $3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

While dabbling in a similar but different problem, I sort of noticed this.

Is it true that $3^n-1$, for all odd $n\in\mathrm{N}$, is no more than once divisible by $2$? If so, is there a conclusive proof for this statement? In other words, if:
$$3^n-1=2a$$
where $a\in\mathrm{N}$, is it true that $a$ must be odd too?

I attempted to disprove this in the following way-

Consider that $n=2k+1$, and $j$ and $a$ where $k,j,a\in\mathrm{N}$ and:
$$\begin{split}
3^n-1&=3\cdot3^{2k}-1\\
&=2^ja
\end{split}$$
Using induction on $k$ here led to the following:
$$ 3\cdot3^2\cdot3^{2k}-1=2^{j}\cdot3^2\cdot a+8$$
which doesn't really put a bound on $j$. I haven't been able to find a counterexample yet which makes me think that the above isn't correct.

So is the statement correct? Please provide an answer with a proof, if possible.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey : That is also only once divisible by $2$. This case is consistent with my statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, $3^n-1=2(1+3+3^2+...+3^{n-1})$

When $n$ is odd there are odd number of odd numbers plus together in the bracket.

Comment: Ah I see. Shouldn't it be $2(1+2+2^2+...+2^{n-1})$?

Comment: Nope, the formula is $a^n-1=(a-1)(1+a+a^2+...+a^{n-1})$

Comment: However, if I do $3^n-1=(1+2)^n-1=2+2^2+2^3+...+2^n$, I get the expression in my previous comment... where is the discrepancy?

Comment: When you expand $(1+2)^n$ you need to use binomial theorem and the sum is far bigger than your sum.

Comment: Sorry, I made a terrible mistake...

Answer (score 2):

Your claim is true. To do it : take $n:=2k+1$ then :

$$3^n-1=3\times 3^{2k}-1=3(3^{2k}-1)+2=3(3^{k}-1)(3^k+1)+2 $$

Now $(3^{k}-1)(3^k+1)$ is divisible by $4$ $($since each factor is divisible by $2$$)$ hence $\frac{(3^{k}-1)(3^k+1)}{2}$ is even. Finally :

$$3^n-1=2\left(3\frac{(3^{k}-1)(3^k+1)}{2}+1\right)$$

This is $2$ times an odd number.

Comment: Ingenious! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=2k+1$ as you did

base case $k=0$
$$3^1-1=2=2\cdot 1$$

Assume it for $k$ with $a$ being odd and we'll show $k+1$
$$3^{2(k+1)+1}=3^{2k+1+2}=3^{2k+1}\cdot 3^2 = 2\cdot a\cdot 9$$
and odd times odd is odd so $9a$ is odd and it holds

Answer (score -2):

$3^n-1\equiv 0 \pmod 4$ if $n$ is a power of $2,n\gt1$.

Comment: Powers of 2 are not odd !

Comment: 1) While true, this doesn't answer the question at all.  2) While true, this completely misses the far more relevant point that $3^n -1 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ iff $n$ is even.